# Heat diffusion a ring with a temperature activated flame using deSolve::ode in R

Tags: r, simulation, ode, differential-equations, desolve

I'm trying to model a ring that is heated at one point if the temperature goes below a certain value. Here's my R code:

```
library(deSolve)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

local({
    heatT <- 100
    v <- c(rep(1, 49), heatT, rep(1, 50))
    alpha <- .02
    fun <- function(t, v, pars) {
        L <- length(v)
        d2T <- c(v[2:L], v[1]) + c(v[L], v[1:(L - 1)]) - 2 * v
        dt <- pars * d2T
        
        # Uncomment to trigger the problem
        #if (v[50] < 25) dt[50] <- 100 - v[50]
        
        return(list(dt - .005 * (v - 1)))
    }
    
    ode(v, 1:200, fun, parms = alpha)
}) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
pivot_longer(-time, values_to = "val", names_to = "x") %>% 
    filter(time %in% round(seq.int(1, 200, length.out = 40))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(as.numeric(x), val)) +
    geom_line(alpha = .5, show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_point(aes(color = val)) +
    scale_color_gradient(low = "#56B1F7", high = "red") +
    facet_wrap(~ time) +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
    labs(x = 'x', y = 'T', color = 'T')
```

The line: `if (v[50] < 25) dt[50] <- 100 - v[50]` tells the model to increase temperature on segment 50 if it goes below 25°.
If this line is commented the model works fine. If the line is active the model fails (asking to increase `maxsteps`) as soon 25° are reached (it still outputs the results until that point).
The model can run successfully if the solving method is switched to "ode45", but then is very slow, or if switched to an explicit method like "euler" but then it works only until alpha is low enough.

Is there a correct way to implement this in order to run it fast with the default implicit methods or it is simply something that ode cannot manage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `if`-line makes the model very stiff. This is not surprising as ODEs are continuous and differentiable by definition. It is not uncommon that this is violated in practical cases but the solvers are, fortunately, quite robust. However, it is always possible to "drive the solvers against a wall", that seems to be the case here. There are several possibilities ins such cases: tune the tolerances, make the signal a little bit smoother by using a less rectangular signal with rounded edges, change the grid. Sometimes, a more robust solver will do. The default `lsoda` is fine for most applications, but in this case `vode` would be better. Replace the call to `ode` with the following line:

```r
ode(v, 1:200, fun, parms = alpha, method = "vode")
```

and it should work without error. `vode` is another excellent solver of the [Livermore ODEPACK](https://computing.llnl.gov/projects/odepack) family. Another approach is to use an external [forcing or an event](https://tpetzoldt.github.io/deSolve-forcing/deSolve-forcing.html).

Comment: Thanks, vode works!!! can you elaborate or provide some references to the other suggestions, like how to tune tolerance, what you mean by making the signal less rectangular, or how to change the grid?

Comment: After a second look, vode produces strange results. Even if the new heat transfer after reaching 25° it's one shot, the peak temperature keeps increasing until it reaches ~65° and then decreases again. With ode45 instead it starts oscillating around 25° which I believe is to be expected with one shot heat bursts, isn't it? what is driving the difference between the two algorithms? of course I'd prefer to use vode since it's way faster.

Comment: Anyway, using root event totally solves the problem, thanks!

Comment: Exactly. This is the most direct way to go. I just started to point you to this approach. Another approach would be an extension of the equations instead if the if, for example with a saturation function (in life sciences and chemistry known as Michelis-Menten or Monod). Regarding `ode45`, I suspect that oscillation is not correct anyway. It sounds plausible, but can be a sign of numerical instability.